# Using python bedparse

Tags: python, bioinformatics

Question from a total newbie.

I need help to use this tool [https://bedparse.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Usage.html#convert-gtf-to-bed](https://www.stackoverflow.com/). Apparently it is a python module. Could somebody enlighten me about where to start?

I have downloaded Python, and apparently I manage to install the module using
`python -m pip install bedparse` from CMD (I use windows).

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python -m pip install bedparse
Requirement already satisfied: bedparse in c:\users\mauricioroza\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (0.2.3)
Collecting argparse
  Using cached argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\mauricioroza\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from bedparse) (65.5.0)
Installing collected packages: argparse
Successfully installed argparse-1.4.0
```

But I don't know what to do from there, I tried `>>> import bedparse` in python and no error message, but if I try any of the commands like `bedparse gtf2bed --help` in python or CMD, but nothing seems to work.

I have some experience with R and bash, but this is really confusing to me.
Maybe I am missing something trivial that I am not aware, since I am not used to python.

If anyone could help me indicating any tutorial or something it would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

`Bedparse` has both command line functionality and can be imported as a module, as shown in [docs](https://bedparse.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Tutorial.html)

```py
from bedparse import bedline

l = bedline(['chr1', 1000, 2000, 'Tx1', '0', '+'])
prom = l.promoter()
prom.print()
# chr1    500     1500    Tx1

prom.pprint()
# ['chr1', 500, 1500, 'Tx1']

ens_prom = prom.translateChr(assembly="hg38", target="ens")
ens_prom.print()
# 1       500     1500    Tx1
```

However, I don't think it supports Windows, just attempting to call any command-line argument shows it tries to use `SIGPIPE`, which is [unsupported in Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#module-contents).

You can use [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) to get around this.